How can I rerender my component after refreshing tokens with apollo client?
I work with apollo client, implementing auth with jwt. I catch the error from back when I try do something when my token is expired, refresh tokens and then resend request. It work like it should, but my component does not rerender, new request sends, I get data, but my component still shows error.
How can I rerender my component with new data?
const errorLink = onError(
    ({ graphQLErrors, networkError, operation, forward }) => {
      if (graphQLErrors) {
        graphQLErrors.forEach(({ message, locations, path }) => {
          console.log(
            `[GraphQL error]: Message: ${message}, Location: ${locations}, Path: ${path}`
          );

          // Handle specific errors
          if (message === "jwt expired") {
            Refreshtoken()
              .then((r) => forward(operation))
              .catch((e) => console.log("@1", e));
          }
          if (
            message ===
            "Access denied! You don't have permission for this action!"
          ) {
            // Call Refreshtoken function or perform any other desired action
            fromPromise(
              Refreshtoken()
                .then((r) => {
                  getNewToken("access-token").then((r) => {
                    operation.setContext({
                      headers: {
                        authorization: `Bearer ${r}`,
                      },
                    });
                    console.log("operation", operation.getContext());
                    return toPromise(forward(operation))                  });
                })
                .catch((e) => console.log("@", e))
            );
          }
          //get new token from cookies
        });
      }

      if (networkError) {
        console.log("@");
        console.log(`[Network error]: ${networkError}`);

        
      }
    }
);

Code from component
const { loading, data } = useQuery(
    GET_ANIME,
    
    { variables: { slug: params.slug }, fetchPolicy: 'no-cache', }
  );

I expect my component will rerender with correct data after I resend request and get data, no error.
I tried change onError code, change cache-policy but it doesn't work for me.

You need to change state in order for a component to re-render. Add a useState hook, and change the value when you receive the data that you want. That will cause the entire component to re-render, but it sounds like in your case the useState hook should likely include the output you're trying to display.
